# SQL: can I JOIN 2 tables according the first table "array" value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

Im trying to find a better way to return 2 tables at once.

My first table is:

```
[ID]       [area]
  1        13,12,15
  6        18,17,13
```

and the second table is:

```
 [areaname]    [singlearea]
 textOf12     12
 textOf18     18
 textOf15     15
```

Now, I need to return for each [ID] hits area names, for example:

**For the ID:** 1, I need the following array: **(textOf12,textOf15)**

and **for the ID 6** I need: **(textOf18)** only.

This is what i have for now (I don't think its a nice code):

```
$getall = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$resultfull = mysql_query($getall);
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultfull))
{
$uarray = array();
$sqlarea = explode(",", $res['area']);

foreach($sqlarea as $userarea)
        {
        $areaarray = runquery("SELECT areaname From table2 WHERE singlearea = '".$userarea."'");
        $value = mysql_fetch_object($areaarray);
        array_push($uarray,$value->areaname);
        }
var_dump($uarray);
```

any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Any suggestions?"  Fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of numbers as comma separated characters.  SQL has a very nice data structure for storing lists.  It is called a table.  The particular type of table in this case is called a junction table.

Comment: considering the data structure this is as much as you can do. Fancy code tricks are not a replacement for a robust database architecture.

Comment: you right, I'll change the structure, Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Comma separated ID list and ID value pretty good matching using `like`:

```
select t1.id, t2.areaname
  from table1 t1, table2 t2
  where concat(',', t1.area, ',') like concat('%,', t2.singlearea, ',%')
```

However It's recommended to use additional link table!